Automatic closing and passing of cookies from chrome custom in app tab
Desired Behaviour
I'm seeking to understand how some android apps are seemingly able to close their custom chrome in app tab - and pass cookies at the same time.
https://youtube.com/shorts/optSV3c4lSk?feature=share
Please see the attached video of the behaviour.
Attempted research
These posts seem to outline that an automatic closing of the custom chrome tab isn't possible, so I'm unsure of what KFC are doing differently.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795847/how-to-close-chrome-custom-tabs#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20such%20support,custom%20tab%20if%20you%20want.
// bring back the main webview
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);

Code like this is all well and good - but how can the original webview be prompted to execute this block if the user is interacting with the custom chrome tab and thus the buttons which might lead to this block?
Would using an intent filter in the web-app code to redirect to the webview application work? In this case, how could the cookies/information be passed back to the app like in the KFC example - or is that handled through the shared cookie jar.
